# Python Markdown 64 bit installation problems

Tags: python, django, 64-bit, markdown

I'm working with Django for python.
I've tried to install Markdown 2.0.3 for python from here http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Markdown but it only has a windows 32 bit version and I have windows 7 64 bit.

When trying to install the 32 bit version an error appears:

> No python installation found in the registry

I do have python 2.7 that works perfectly with Django.

Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no 64 or 32 bit version of this module. Markdown is a pure-python module and you can install it that way. If the `.exe` doesn't work for you for some reason, you can always download the `.zip` version, unpack and run `python setup.py install` in that directory (provided that python is in your `PATH`)